# omnifaces não reconhe CDI configurado no tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, cdi, java-ee-7

Bom dia a todos. Estou fazendo o projeto do livro **"algaworks-ebook-java-ee-7-com-jsf-primefaces-e-cdi-2a-edicao-20150228"** e estou com problemas na hora de adicionar o omnifaces.

Quando vou subir o tomcat, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
...
INFO: WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
mai 26, 2016 10:13:07 AM org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer logOmniFacesVersion
INFORMAÇÕES: Using OmniFaces version 2.3
mai 26, 2016 10:13:07 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener contextInitialized
INFO: WELD-ENV-001006: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener used for ServletContext notifications
mai 26, 2016 10:13:07 AM org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener checkCDIAvailable
GRAVE: 
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
?                         ??     ?                                             ?
?    ?                  ?????    ? OmniFaces failed to initialize!             ?
?   ????               ??????    ?                                             ?
?   ??????            ???????    ? This OmniFaces version requires CDI, but    ?
?   ???????          ???????     ? none was found on this environment.         ?
?    ???????????????????????     ?                                             ?
?    ???????????????????????     ? OmniFaces 2.x requires a minimum of JSF 2.2.?
?     ?????????????????????      ? Since this JSF version, the JSF managed bean?
?     ?????????????????????      ? facility @ManagedBean is semi-official      ?
?     ??????????????????????     ? deprecated in favour of CDI. JSF 2.2 users  ?
?     ??????????????????????     ? are strongly encouraged to move to CDI.     ?
?     ??????????????????????     ?                                             ?
?    ???????????????????????     ? OmniFaces goes a step further by making CDI ?
?    ????????????????????????    ? a REQUIRED dependency next to JSF 2.2. This ?
?    ????????????????????????    ? not only ensures that your web application  ?
?   ???????????????? ????????    ? represents the state of art, but this also  ?
?   ?????????????????????????    ? makes for us easier to develop OmniFaces,   ?
?   ??????????????????????????   ? without the need for all sorts of hacks in  ?
?   ??????????????????????????   ? in order to get OmniFaces to deploy on      ?
?  ????????????????????????????  ? environments without CDI.                   ?
?  ????????????????????????????  ?                                             ?
?  ????????????????????????????  ? You have 3 options:                         ?
?????????????????????????????????? 1. Downgrade to OmniFaces 1.x.              ?
?????????????????????????????????? 2. Install CDI in this environment.         ?
?????????????????????????????????? 3. Switch to a CDI capable environment.     ?
??????????????????????????????????                                             ?
?????????????????????????????????? For additional instructions, check          ?
?????????????????????????????????? http://omnifaces.org/cdi                    ?
??????????????????????????????????                                             ?
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
...
```

Lembrando que:

- Ambiente (Tomcat 8, Java 8)
- Já tenho Weld CDI configurado e funcionando

**Pom:**

```
    <!-- Weld (implementação do CDI) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OmniFaces (utilitarios para JSF) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**context.xml** no diretório src/main/webapp/META-INF :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Manager pathname="" />
    <Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
        javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

**beans.xml** - No diretório src/main/resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

    <interceptors>
        <class>
            com.algaworks.util.TransactionInterceptor
        </class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

Answer (score -1):

A solução não é minha, mais como parece ser o mesmo problema ao qual passei posto a solução encontra ao qual resolveu o meu problema...

> "O problema é o artefato, mas se você usar essa versão vai funcionar
>
> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet/2.2.1.Final
>
> se estiver usando Maven esse é o procedimento
>
> coloca a referencia no `pom.xml`"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Link da fonte: http://respostas.guj.com.br/27537-weld---javalangillegalstateexception-singleton-is-not-set